# Extracting article links only using jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am trying to use JSoup to extract links of articles from stock symbols.

For example on this page: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/p?s=+AAPL+Press+Releases
there are a bunch of press release titles. When you press each title, you are given a link. I want to use JSoup to extract and store the links of each one of those press releases.

As of now this is what I have so far:

```
   Document doc = Jsoup
            .connect("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/p?s=AAPL+Press+Releases").get();
```

And to get the links I am using

```
Elements url = jSoupDoc.select("p").select("a");
System.out.println(url.text());
```

The output that I am getting is not the link only, I am getting some other information with it. Please help me tweak the .select() statements to get only the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    Document document = Jsoup.connect("http://finance.yahoo.com/q/p?s=+AAPL+Press+Releases")
                         .get();
    Element div = document.select("div.mod.yfi_quote_headline.withsky").first();
    Elements aHref = div.select("a[href]");
    for(Element element : aHref)
        System.out.println(element.attr("abs:href"));
```

Output:

> http://finance.yahoo.com/news/hagens-berman-payday-millions-e-161500428.html
>   http://finance.yahoo.com/news/swift-playgrounds-app-makes-learning-185500537.html
>   http://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-previews-ios-10-biggest-185500113.html
>   http://finance.yahoo.com/news/powerful-siri-capabilities-single-sign-185500577.html
>   http://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-previews-major-macos-sierra-185500097.html
>   http://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-previews-watchos-3-faster-185500388.html
>   http://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-union-square-highlights-design-173000006.html
>   http://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-opens-development-office-hyderabad-043000495.html
>   http://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-announces-ios-app-design-043000238.html
>   http://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-celebrates-chinese-music-garageband-230000088.html
>   http://finance.yahoo.com/news/apple-sap-partner-revolutionize-iphone-183000583.html